# Proper Granularity for Mutex Lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I am working on a program that prints regex matches from several threads searching the filesystem and each thread adds its id to a queue and notifies the main thread that there are some threads to be removed from the thread pool which is a std::vector.

> At this point, I am unlocking and locking the mutex whenever I perform
>   an operation on the resource to be protected. It feels like I'm
>   thinking of this all wrong and that I'm being way too granular. Would
>   it be better to lock the mutex before entering the while loop, unlock
>   it after popping the queue, and then locking it again before
>   !finished_threads.empty() is called on the next iteration?

```
void RegexSearch::Run()
{
    running = true;
    search_pool.push_back(std::thread([&] { StartPrint(); }));

    /*
    Get directories and create another thread for each subdirectory while there are
    less threads than maximum in the pool.
    */

    fs::path searchDir(directory);

    for (const auto& dir : searchDir)
    {
        if (search_pool.size() >= MAX_THREADS)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mu, std::defer_lock);
            // Wait to be notified that thread is finished execution and another can start.
            max_thread_cond.wait(lck);

            lck.lock();
            while (!finished_threads.empty())
            {
                lck.unlock();

                lck.lock();
                std::thread::id remove_thread = finished_threads.front();
                lck.unlock();

                lck.lock();
                finished_threads.pop();
                lck.unlock();

                std::remove_if(search_pool.begin(), search_pool.end(), [&remove_thread](const std::thread::id &t) { return remove_thread == t; });
                lck.lock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly have to keep the lock from the test for `!empty()` until you have removed the item from the queue. Otherwise several threads might try to remove the same item - perhaps the last one.

I also see that the `push_back` at the start of the function is unprotected. If there might be several threads accessing the `search_pool`, it must be guarded as well.

Comment: Oh, that makes perfect sense. There are no threads accessing thread_pool before Run() is called. Is it still necessary to lock that down with a mutex?

Comment: The standard containers are not thread safe, so if more threads might access the container while it is updated, there must be a lock. If you are only reading, or there is only one thread accessing a specific container, you are safe anyway.